# ClassCastException when using androidx.fragment.app

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, classcastexception

I'm developing a music player app which makes use of fragments, but I noticed that whilst on my Galaxy S9 with Pie no exceptions are thrown, on my Galaxy S5 mini with KitKat a `java.lang.ClassCastException` is thrown on main activity launch. I also tried on an API 19 emulator and even there the exception is thrown. It seems to be thrown inside or after `onStart()`, I don't know exactly. My own opinion is that, since not a single row of my code is mentioned in exception stack trace, it is a `androidx.fragment.app` library bug.

Here it is the mentioned stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.configureTransitionsOrdered(FragmentTransition.java:314)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:138)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1862)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1820)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1726)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please excuse me for my grammar mistakes, if there are any; I'm Italian and I'm currently studying English at school.

Comment: Seems like you're passing the `R.id` of a View to your `FragmentTransaction` instead of the `R.id` of a ViewGroup. What is the layout you're using on that device and your `FragmentTransaction` code look like?

Comment: In `FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment)` I'm passing the id of a `FrameLayout`. It is a runtime built layout, no xml files.

Comment: Am getting exactly the same message, but have no idea where it comes from. Did you resolve that? Thanks.